# Properties changing in a custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

[image: Link to Image]

I've created a custom control for easy addition as rows to a `TableLayoutPanel`. One entire row as seen in the image is a single instance of the control. I've to implement some functionality so that whenever rate and quantity are filled, the (complete) change should cause a `sum += (rate * quantity)` in the Total box.

What I was thinking of was something on the lines of a `OnPropertyChanged` event handler inside `ProductControl.cs`, which is the class for the custom control. I surmise that I would need two property change handlers, one for `Rate` and one for `Quantity`. Each would check whether the other field is empty or not, and proceed to update a `Product = Rate*Quantity` value.

However, how would I access these handlers in the **main form**? I need to update the `Total` box as `Total += (Rate*Quantity)` or `Total += Product`.

Source for `ProductControl.cs` -:

```
public partial class ProductControl : UserControl
{
        Dictionary<int, PairClass<string, double>> PC = new Dictionary<int, PairClass<string, double>>();
        public string Number
        {
            get
            {
                return ProdNo.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                ProdNo.Text = value;
            }
        }
        public ProductControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetMapping(Dictionary<int, PairClass<string, double>> map)
        {
            PC = map;
        }

        //This implements the functionality that whenever a Product Number is entered,
        //the Product Name and Rate appear automatically, by virtue of a mapping
        //between Product Number: Pair<Product Name, Rate>.
        private void ProdNoText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            PairClass<string, double> pc = null;
            if (int.TryParse(ProdNoText.Text, out x))
            {
                PC.TryGetValue(x, out pc);
                if (pc != null)
                {
                    PNameText.Text = pc.First;
                    RateText.Text = pc.Second.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom event for your control like this:

You first create the class `ProductChangedEventArgs` derived from `EventArgs` and containing all the informations the main form will need to handle che product change (let's say `Rate` and `Quantity`). This class only needs a constructor that accepts `Rate` and `Quantity` and two public getters.

Then, in your class:

```
// This will be the signature of your event handlers
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, ProductChangedEventArgs e);
// The event itself to which will be possible to bind callbacks functions
//   with the signature given by ChangedEventHandler
public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

protected virtual void OnChanged(ProductChangedEventArgs e) 
{
  // This checks there's at least one callback bound to the event
  if (Changed != null){
    // If there are callbacks, call all of them
    Changed(this, e);
  }
}
```

Now all you need to do, is call `OnChanged` in whichever point you want the event to be emitted from.

You will, for example, call it in the setters of all your product properties.

```
private int _rate;
public int Rate{
  set{
    if(_rate != value){
      _rate = value;
      // Call the callbacks passing an EventArgs that reflects the actual state
      //   of the product
      OnChanged(this, new ProductChangedEventArgs(_rate, ... ));
    }
  }
}
```

Now in the main form, you can bind callbacks to the `Changed` event like so:

```
productControl1.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler( callback );
```

Comment: In your first code section, that should be `ProductChangedEventArgs` instead of `ChangedEventArgs`, right?

Comment: I haven't been able to test it thoroughly due to the application requiring a network connection to the database (happening only during server up-hours). I think this is the right way though, so accepting answer.

Comment: Thanks, come back here if you need more help on this.